# What happens to my site if I go over my quota for PageSpeed API? I don't have a billing account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, pagespeed, billing

What happens to my site if I go over my quota for Page Speed API? What does Google Cloud do? I don't have a billing account. I searched Google for answers and opened links associated with Google Cloud. What I found suggests that Google sends error messages. Do these appear on my website? I don't want people to be blocked or see any error messages over this.

How many Google Page Speed Requests is a small site likely to get if it has less than 10000 visitors per month?

Will Google throttle my site if it gets more than the alloted quota? How much?

Comment: If you are over "free" quota, you will get a 429 http error code mentioning quota exceeded.

Comment: Awesome, @guillaumeblaquiere. Thank you. Do you happen to know the free quota?

Comment: Are you looking for this page? (expend the query accordion) https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/pagespeedonline.googleapis.com/quotas

Comment: Thank you, @guillaumeblaquiere. Is this my data from my account? If so, it says no data. Perhaps I don't have it set up as well as I thought I did.

Comment: check that you have the correct Google Project select.